# What privileges does the first user of snowflake gets?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand that the first user of the snowflake will be an Accountadmin. But, What other roles does he have access to by default, and does only the first user of the snowflake have Accountadmin role access by default?

Answer (score 0):

The default set of role that a user gets is Public. Along with this, the administrator designated user has accountadmin role assigned to it.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-user-management.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-user-management.html#user-roles

The accountadmin role can be assigned to different users if there is a requirement for multiple admins but this should be a very careful exercise.

Comment: Srinath, I'm not concerned about all the users. I'm curious to know that how many users get the Account Admin access after setting up the account (Is it only the first user or first three users) and what are the roles they get by default (Is it only the Account Admin role or Security Admin, Sys Admin & User Admin too)

Comment: There is no such first or first three users concepts. The first user is usually assigned accountadmin role and designated as the administrator for Snowflake.
From then on it is entirely requirement based how many more users should be given the accountadmin role.

Comment: Okay, It's only the first user then. Along with Account Admin role what other roles he/she has access to by default such as Security Admin, Sys Admin & User Admin

Comment: Yes, these 4 roles too are assigned to the user.

Comment: Great! Thanks Srinath!

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a new account (trial / on-demand) you get ACCOUNTADMIN and every role.

If you are on capacity plan the first user gets the four roles as described

Through design of an established account, i.e. you're a customer and an administrator in your company has set up access for you then you can set up with a default role

If you are not, and no admin has been done to assign a role to you then you get public, which (if properly designed) gives you access to nothing ;)